# Caching of DB queries in django

Tags: python, database, django, caching

I have django app that uses two external scripts. One script moves a file from A to B, stores the value for B in a database - and exists afterwards, which should commit any possibly open transactions. The next script reacts to movement of the file (using inotify), calculates md5sum (which appearently takes time) and then looks for an entry in the database like
`x = Queue.get(filename=location)`.
Looking at the timestamps of my logs, I am 100% sure that the first script is long done before the second script (actually a daemon) runs the query. Interestingly enough, the thing works perfectly after a restart of daemon.

This leads me to believe that somehow the Queryset (I actually run the code shown above everytime a new file is detected with inotify) is cached during runtime of the daemon. I however would not want to restart the daemon all the time, but instead force the query to actually use the DB instead of that cache.

The django documentation doesn't say much about that - however usually django is not used as an external :)

Thank you in advance for any hints!

Ben

PS: as per request the source of the relevant part from the daemon

```
def _get_info(self, path):
    try:
        obj = Queue.objects.get(filename=path)
        x = obj.x
        return x
    except Exception, e:
        self.logger.error("Error in lookup: %s" % e)
        return None
```

This is called by a thread everytime a new file is moved to the watched directory

Whereas the code in the first script looks like

```
for f in Queue.objects.all():
    if (matching_stuff_here):
         f.filename = B
         f.save()    
         sys.exit(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shown any actual code, so we have to guess. My guess would be that even though the transaction in the first script is done and committed, you're still inside an open transaction in script B: and because of transaction isolation, you won't see any changes in B until you finish the transaction there.

Comment: I updated my post to include the relevant source snippets. 

However, as far as I grasp the whole thing, I would have to force the transaction to end after each lookup in the daemon, right?